# How do I solve this ominous integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, zeta-functions, catalans-constant

Let $ n\ge 1 $ be a positive integer. How do I prove the generalization: $$ \int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\log^{2n}(x)}{1+x} \, dx =\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-2^{-2 n}\right) \zeta(2 n+1)(2 n)!+\frac{1}{2} \beta(2 n+2)(2 n) !-\frac{\pi}{16} \lim _{s \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{d^{2 n}}{d s^{2 n}}\left(\csc \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)\right.\right.$$

The integral was offered to me by my good friend and it looks very difficult, I managed to solve only for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log^2(x)}{1+x} \, dx=\frac{21}{64}\pi\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^3}{32}\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{24}G;$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log^4(x)}{1+x} \, dx=\frac{1395}{256}\pi\zeta(5)-\frac{9}{128}\pi^3\zeta(3)-\frac{7}{480}\pi^4G-\frac{5}{128}\pi^5\log(2)+\frac{\pi^6}{192}-\frac{\pi^2}{1536}\psi^{(3)}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right).$$

where $G$ represents the Catalan’s constant.

Comment: Please say in your post what $G$ means: it's not a universally understood mathematical notation like $\pi$ or $e$.  I am also dubious about calling your formulas "closed form" since you are expressing them in terms of numbers like $\zeta(3)$ that have no simple formula, so $\zeta(3)$ itself has no known closed form expression. You're expressing one unknown thing in terms of several other unknown things. You might as well say the integral itself its own "closed form" (nonstandard use of that term).

Comment: @KCd G - Catalan's constant. I don't know how to express it specifically, but here you need to confirm a certain generalization, where ζ represents the Riemann zeta function, ψ denotes the Digamma
function, and β designates the Dirichlet beta function. Well, at least this is all the information that I have)

Comment: @KCd Take a look, I added more information, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general "closed-form" is:
$$\int _0^1\frac{\arctan \left(x\right)\ln ^{2n}\left(x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi }{4}\left(1-2^{-2n}\right)\zeta \left(2n+1\right)\left(2n\right)!+\frac{1}{2}\beta \left(2n+2\right)\left(2n\right)!-\frac{\pi }{16}$$
$$\lim _{s\to 0}\left(\frac{d^{2n}}{ds^{2n}}\left(\csc \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\left(\psi \left(\frac{3-s}{4}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1-s}{4}\right)\right)+\sec \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\left(\psi \left(1-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)-2\pi \csc \left(\pi s\right)\right)\right)$$
And you may find its evaluation in the book *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series* through pages $140-145$ where double integration, symmetry and the following result are heavily exploited:
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^s}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y^2x^2\right)}\:dx=\frac{\pi }{2}\csc \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\frac{y^{-s}}{1+y^2}+\frac{\pi }{2}\sec \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\frac{y^{1-s}}{1+y^2}-\frac{\pi \csc \left(\pi s\right)}{1+y^2}$$